# Trying to use koin but doesnt work correctly on android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin

I'm trying to implement Koin in my project. So far, I did this:

My shared preferences class:

```
class MPCUtilSharedPreference(private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences{}
```

I want to inject that class in other classes. So, I create my MainApplication class:

```
class MPCMainApplication : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    startKoin {
        androidContext(this@MPCMainApplication)
        modules(modules)
    }
}
```

}

This is my module class:

```
private val appModule = module {
single {
    MPCUtilSharedPreference(
        androidContext().getSharedPreferences(
            BuildConfig.APP_PREFERENCE,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )
    )
  }
}
val modules = listOf(appModule)
```

And the I'm trying to inject it:

```
class MPCNetworkInterceptor : Interceptor {

private val utilSharedPreferences: MPCUtilSharedPreference by inject() }
```

The error says:

> No value passed for parameter 'clazz'

I'm trying to use

```
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidContext
```

But the AS uses

```
import org.koin.java.KoinJavaComponent.inject
```

This is my gradle:

```
implementation 'org.koin:koin-android:2.1.5'
implementation 'org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:2.1.5'
implementation 'org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:2.1.5'
implementation 'org.koin:koin-androidx-fragment:2.1.5'
```

Any idea about what's the problem here?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the context and let your implementation select preferences file and mode internally? Can you post full error message?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're trying to use `by inject()` delegate from an place that is neither an Activity nor Fragment, that's why the IDE is importing :

```
import org.koin.java.KoinJavaComponent.inject
```

If you want to use `MPCUtilSharedPreference` from `MPCNetworkInterceptor`, you can pass it as parameter in `MPCNetworkInterceptor` constructor. And obviously, add this in your module.

Otherwise, you could implement `KoinComponent`

Answer (score 6):

I dont know, why `koin` is  not able to suggest `org.koin.android.ext.android.inject` path when using `by inject()` but I fixed this issue with below code snippet:

```kotlin
private val foo: FooClass by KoinJavaComponent.inject(FooClass::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I see couple of approaches mentioned in other solutions on this thread but not the most obvious one (probably because the answers were given way back).

Why not simply implement an interface named `KoinComponent`?
Following is the import:

```
import org.koin.core.component.KoinComponent
```

With this, you can simply inject the object to any class you like.

Following is the example where I have used this approach with success:

```
import org.koin.core.component.KoinComponent
import org.koin.core.component.inject

class MyViewModel() : ViewModel(), KoinComponent {

val locationHelperImpl by inject<LocationHelperImpl>()
```

This interface unlocks the extenstions from Koin for the given class and you can simply use the inject method like I have shown.